# What's the purpose of each of the different UIDs a process can have?

Tags: linux, security, unix

Real UID, effective UID, and some systems even have a "saved UID". What's the purpose of all these, especially the last one?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Each UNIX process has 3 UIDs associated to it. Superuser privilege is UID=0.

**Real UID**

This is the UID of the user/process that created THIS process. It can be changed only if the running process has EUID=0.

**Effective UID**

This UID is used to evaluate privileges of the process to perform a particular action. EUID can be changed either to RUID, or SUID if EUID!=0. If EUID=0, it can be changed to anything.

**Saved UID**

If you run an executable with the set-UID bit set, then the resulting running process will start off with a real UID of the real user running it, and an effective and saved UID of the owner of the executable file. If the process then calls setuid() or seteuid() to change their effective UID, they can still get back their original privileges again thanks to the saved UID. If the set-UID bit is not set, SUID will be the RUID.

Comment: What's the purpose of Saved UID?

Comment: It's for security and audit purposes, i.e. to be able to determine which user account actually launched the binary? If it weren't around, all you would be able to get is the file owner's UID since running with the file owner privileges is what the SUID bit is for.

Comment: The saved UID is so a process can switch its effective UID to its real UID, then back again; otherwise it would be a one-way operation.

Comment: I tried to clarify the purpose of the Saved UID with what you said MarkR.

Comment: @Jim: No; evaluate is correct.  The effective UID is the number that's checked when deciding (evaluating) whether a file can be accessed or not.  The real UID does not affect that decision.

Comment: "It can be changed only if the running process has EUID=0."
@Barth I don't think the above statement is correct for Real UID, or any other UID.
It is true that any UID can be changed to arbitrary values only if EUID = 0.   But any user can change any UID into one of the RUID, EUID or EUID no matter what the current EUID, RUID or SUID is.
I have verified this and suggested an edit for the answer but I don't understand why it was rejected. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 7):

The real uid is the id of the user that launched a process.

The effective uid typically is the same as the real uid. It is different only if:

- the executable had the set-uid bit set, and the executable owner is different than the user calling it
- or if a set-uid process calls setuid(2). If the process has superuser privileges, any argument to setuid(2) is allowed (but then all *-uids get set to the same value); otherwise, setuid(2) can be called with the real-uid or the effective-uid or the saved-uid.

The saved-uid is the effective-uid the process had when it started, and it's saved in order to be allowed as an argument to the various set*uid system calls.

Note that a process with superuser privilege calling setuid(2) to change its effective uid will also have the real uid and saved uid changed to the same value, so the non-POSIX seteuid(2) should be used instead.

All of the above apply to (real|effective|saved) group ids too.

Comment: Second bullet isn't correct - calling setuid() will not, of itself, make the EUID different from the RUID unless the process previously had RUID != EUID (so it might reinstate the state at program start).  The rest of the bullet is more or less accurate.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; I believe I corrected the second bullet by adding one word.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the real, effective, and saved UIDs, Unix systems with auditing enabled also have the audit UID.  A process's AUID identifies the user who started the process; it is not changed by setuid(2) or seteuid(2).  The intent is that it remains constant through the process and is used only to tag audit records.  Thus, if a user executes a privileged shell (even an authorized user via su or sudo), the audit records of that process are tagged from that user.

Answer (score 2):

Each Linux process has 3 UIDs associated to it.

- **Real UID**: The UID of the process that created THIS process.
- **Effective UID**: This is used to evaluate privileges of the process to perform a particular action.
- **Saved UID**: For the binary image file with a `setuid` bit on it.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is not correct regarding that real UD's can not be changed by anyone except root.
From the man page for setuid:
(I could not make a comment)

> The setuid() function sets the real and effective user IDs and the
>   saved set-user-ID of
>        the current process to the specified value.  The setuid() function is permitted if the
>        effective user ID is that of the super user, or if the specified user ID is the same as
>        the effective user ID.  If not, but the specified user ID is the same as the real user
>        ID, setuid() will set the effective user ID to the real user ID.